# CSS is different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem regarding the layout of my css. When i use Firefox the layout is ok. Just like i want to. But in Chrome there is a big difference. I have used css reset but it just messed up with my css. I don't know what to do, every tip will be helpful.

http: //83.212.122.240/

My site is in Greek.

There are differences in the navigation buttons and in my login form between the two browsers.

Here is my code: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u68pv6t91p3lk24/index.html

And my css:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa7alsvsfhw62qy/templatemo_style.css

Comment: I tried giving style in input and problem get resolved : <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" style="height:18px; line-height:18px;">
Check my below answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check browser behavior for text-boxes only. You have to fix height and line-height of all text boxes as below :

```
 .text-box {
   height : 18px;
   line-height : 18px;
   padding : 2px;
  }
```

Line height will take care of the text filled in text-box.

All browser is very sensitive to CSS. So you have to define all rules in CSS so that it should be same in all browsers.

So you have to take care of CSS for every DIV.

Comment: Ok thanks, that was really helpful about the login. The other problem i had is about the navigation buttons. In firefox they are small and nice but in chrome they are really big like they are zoomed. The size of the images are 24x24 so it is really confusing why they are so big

Comment: Same effect will be there. Apply proper css for these buttons.